# Is the month field really deprecated?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, jabref, date

Jabref 3.8.2 has a tab with `Deprecated fields` including the field `Month`.

[image: Jabref]

The Biblatex documentation 3.12 still describes the field month and I could not find a sign of deprecation:

[image: Section 2.3.9 Months and Journal Issues]

Was it wrong by Jabref to call `month` deprecated? Is there a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on your definition of 'deprecated', I'd say. The `biblatex` documentation does not literally say `month` (or `year`, where the situation is the same) is deprecated.

But the documentation of the `year` field ends with

> It is however better to use the `date` field as this is compatible with plain years too and supports many more features.

and similarly the documentation for `month` says

> It is however better to use the `date` field as this supports many more features.

To me that seems sufficient reason for JabRef to place both of these fields in the 'deprecated' section and prefer `date` instead when it is in `biblatex` mode.

It is unlikely that `year` and `month` will cease to work in `biblatex`, because that would be a backwards compatibility nightmare. But as far as I am concerned I'd definitely recommend `date` over `year` and `month` (if you don't need compatibility with classic BibTeX).

---

The next version of `biblatex` will have slightly more explicit advice on `year`/`month` vs `date` in the docs: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/7d7c682f9ec7f06aadd4f176dcfcdadb9afe33ea